# How to use Hierarchical decision voter using global method security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Below is my spring security XML configuration whole code.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
           xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd">

    <!-- Definition of the Authentication Service
     For Authenticating a User the Client application will send request to the URL "/oauth/token". This request will contain the clientId, client password, userName and user password details
     -->
    <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"  authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" >
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
        <anonymous enabled="false"/>
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
        <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/> <!-- http/http-basic -->
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
    </http>

    <http pattern="/**"  entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
        <anonymous enabled="false"/>
        <custom-filter ref="specializedResourceServerFilter"
                       before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
    </http>

    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint"/>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="client"/>
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler"/>
    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="oAuth2authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager">
        <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices"/>
        <property name="resourceId" value="myId"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="specializedResourceServerFilter" class="com.my.backend.authentication.oauth2.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingCustomFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="oAuth2authenticationManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="customAuthenticationManager"
          class="com.my.backend.read.rest.authentication.MyDBAuthenticationProvider"/>

    <bean id="myJDBCAuthenticationProvider"
          class="com.my.backend.authentication.MyJDBCAuthenticationProvider"/>

    <!-- Authentication in config file -->
    <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService"/>
    </authentication-manager>
    <!-- authentication Manager called auto and their provider is called -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationManager"/>
        <authentication-provider ref="myJDBCAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Token Store  -->
    <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore">
        <constructor-arg ref="jdbcDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcDataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="#{systemProperties['JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING']}/#{systemProperties['DATABASE']}?autoReconnect=true"/>
        <property name="username" value="#{systemProperties['USER_NAME']}"/>
        <property name="password" value="#{systemProperties['PASSWORD']}"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="tokenServices" class="com.my.backend.authentication.oauth2.CustomTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true"/>
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails"/>
        <!-- VIV -->
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="7776000"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userApprovalHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
        <property name="requestFactory" ref="oAuth2RequestFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="oAuth2RequestFactory"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- Token management -->
    <oauth:authorization-server   client-details-service-ref="clientDetails"  token-services-ref="tokenServices"
                                  user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
        <oauth:implicit/>
        <oauth:refresh-token/>
        <oauth:client-credentials/>
        <oauth:password/>
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:resource-server  id="resourceServerFilter"
                            token-services-ref="tokenServices"/>


    <!-- Client Definition -->
    <bean id="clientDetails"
          class="com.my.backend.authentication.oauth2.JdbcClientDetailsService" >
        <constructor-arg name="dataSource" ref="jdbcDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
        <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler"/>
    </sec:global-method-security>
    <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler"/>
    <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler"/>

</beans>
```

When I hit the restricted URL following these access decision voter involve for authorization with Affirmative access decision manager:

```
0 = {PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter@11611} 
1 = {RoleVoter@11635} 
2 = {AuthenticatedVoter@11639}
```

Although I have not set any access decision manager in above XML configuration I think it is called by default I don't know how. Anyways I wanted to add hierarchical access decision voter so I created my own access decision manager and refer hierarchical in it and refer it in http element like this:

```
 <http pattern="/**" access-decision-manager-ref="*myAccessDecisionManager*" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
    <anonymous enabled="false"/>
    <custom-filter ref="specializedResourceServerFilter"
                   before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</http>
```

It does call but after that those three default access decision voter also called I don't know how to overide it. Please help ...

Edited:

As figure out how the access decision voter can be set mentioned below and now i am stuck in HirarichalRoleVoter I have mentioned below I want to allow customer to access method when it has public role @PreAuthorize("harRole('ROLE_PUBLIC')". 
But it is unable to access it.

```
 <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <ref bean="roleVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleHierarchyVoter">
        <constructor-arg ref="roleHierarchy" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="roleHierarchy"
          class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
        <property name="hierarchy">
            <value>
                ROLE_CUSTOMER > ROLE_PUBLIC
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"  >
        <sec:expression-handler ref="methodSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
    </sec:global-method-security>


    <bean id = "methodSecurityExpressionHandler"
                class = "org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <property name = "roleHierarchy"  ref="roleHierarchy"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Could you please show your `myAccessDecisionManager` code and definition?

Comment: Asked here again proper way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579788/hierarchical-role-voter-not-working-with-global-method-security

Answer (score 1):

`myAccessDecisionManager` is not shown, but I assume that it extends `org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased` or its parent `AbstractAccessDecisionManager`. If that's so, then you could try use `decisionVoters` property like this:

```
<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <property name="decisionVoters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

specifiying whatever voters you like.

Another option is to make a shortcut and avoid using voters: just hardcode your decision-making logic inside your decision manager implementation.

Comment: Where should i refer accessDecisonManager object ?

Comment: You already do it, don't you? `access-decision-manager-ref="*myAccessDecisionManager*"`

Comment: These default voters with affirmative were calling from global-method-security affirmative based. Anyways its done but now I am stuck in role hierarchy.

 `code`<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <ref bean="roleVoter" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>`code`

Comment: `code` <bean id="roleHierarchy"
          class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
        <property name="hierarchy">
            <value>
                ROLE_CUSTOMER > ROLE_PUBLIC
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"  >
        <sec:expression-handler ref="methodSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
    </sec:global-method-security>
`code`

Comment: <bean id = "methodSecurityExpressionHandler"
                class = "org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <property name = "roleHierarchy"  ref="roleHierarchy"/>
    </bean>

Comment: Sorry for formatting. But i have role hierarchy does not allow customer when Method contains annotation @PreAuthorized('ROLE_PUBLIC')

Comment: Could you please update the question with proper formatting? It is hard to read. Also, did you question remain the same ('how to change voters list'), or is it something different due to some progress? If it is different, please state this in your question as well.